# gulp system cannot find the path specified

Tags: typescript, npm, gulp

Hello I have a project that uses gulp and the gulpfile.js suddenly has stop working despite not being changed.

my output reads

cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
The system cannot find the path specified.

gulpfile.js

```
/// <binding ProjectOpened='watchTS' />
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less'),
    path = require('path'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    del = require('del'),
    ts = require('gulp-typescript'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    tslint = require('gulp-tslint'),
    sloc = require('gulp-sloc'),
    debug = require('gulp-debug'),
    typedoc = require('gulp-typedoc');
    
var lib = './lib/';

var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json');

gulp.task('init',function(){
    del.sync('./lib/');
    gulp.src([
        './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        './node_modules/d3/d3.min.js',
        './node_modules/angular/angular.min.js',
        './node_modules/n3-charts/build/LineChart.min.js',
        './node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js',
        './node_modules/floatthead/dist/jquery.floatThead.min.js',
        './node_modules/angular-google-chart/ng-google-chart.min.js',
        './node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'
     ])
    .pipe(concat('lib.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('lib'));

    gulp.src([
        './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
        './node_modules/n3-charts/build/LineChart.min.css'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('lib'))
});

gulp.task('slocTS', function () {
    return gulp.src(['FrontEnd/**/*.ts'])
    //.pipe(debug())
    .pipe(sloc({ tolerant: true }))
})

gulp.task('slocJS', function () {
    return gulp.src(['Scripts/**/*.js'])
    //.pipe(debug())
    .pipe(sloc())
})

/** Builds out documentation for our enviroment on the typescript side*/
gulp.task('buildDocs', function () {
    return gulp.src(['FrontEnd/**/*.ts'])
        .pipe(typedoc({
            target: 'es5',
            out: 'FrontEnd/docs/',
            mode: 'file'
        }));
})

gulp.task('buildTSLogin', function () {
    return gulp.src(['FrontEnd/**/*.ts', '!FrontEnd/ApplicationStartup.ts'])
    .pipe(tslint())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    .pipe(concat('loginApp.js'))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('lib'));
});

gulp.task('buildTS', function () {
    return gulp.src(['FrontEnd/ApplicationStartup.ts', 'FrontEnd/**/*.ts'])
    .pipe(tslint())
    .pipe(tslint.report('verbose', {
        emitError: false
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    /*.pipe(uglify({
        mangle:true
    }))*/
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('lib'));
});

gulp.task('buildProductionTSLogin', function () {
    return gulp.src(['FrontEnd/**/*.ts', '!FrontEnd/ApplicationStartup.ts'])
    .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    .pipe(concat('loginApp.js'))
    .pipe(uglify({
        mangle: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('lib'));
});

gulp.task('buildProductionTS', function () {
    return gulp.src(['FrontEnd/ApplicationStartup.ts', 'FrontEnd/**/*.ts'])
    /*.pipe(tslint())
    .pipe(tslint.report('verbose', {
        emitError: false
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())*/
    .pipe(ts(tsProject))
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(uglify({
        mangle: true
    }))
    /*.pipe(sourcemaps.write())*/
    .pipe(gulp.dest('lib'));
});

gulp.task('buildProduction', ['init', 'buildProductionTSLogin'], function () {
    gulp.start('buildProductionTS');
})

gulp.task('watchTS', function () {
    gulp.watch('FrontEnd/**/*.ts', function (event) {
        console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...');
        gulp.start('buildTS');
        //gulp.start('buildTSLogin');
    });
})
```

and my packages.json contains

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sloc": "^1.0.4",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
    "gulp-tslint": "^3.6.0",
    "gulp-typedoc": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.14.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/angular-route": "^1.7.1",
    "@types/angular-ui-bootstrap": "^0.13.46",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "@uirouter/angularjs": "^1.0.28",
    "angular": "^1.4.5",
    "angular-google-chart": "^0.1.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.5",
    "angular-ui-bootstrap": "^2.5.6",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "d3": "^3.5.16",
    "floatthead": "^1.4.5",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "n3-charts": "^2.0.14"
  }
```

I inherited this project so I don't yet fully understand everything that this is doing, but it has been functioning for years and just gave out.

I did both recently update typescript and changed the project from using a typings folder to using @types (I know typings is really outdated, but that is where the project was) but the project was working since the update and stopped working some time later. I did ensure that all the mentioned packages are installed and all the files are correctly in the node_modules folder. Also the project builds in visual studio error free.

Edit:
after messing around with it I realized that interestingly if I go to the path and run the gulp commands from above from the cli they successfully run.

Edit2:
Im pulling my hair out over this one. My task runner explorer shows this output.

```
cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
The system cannot find the path specified.

cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
The system cannot find the path specified.

cmd.exe /c gulp --tasks-simple
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending more time than I care to admit debugging this I finally figured it out. It ended up being that I had to move my $(PATH) up under visual studio locations of external tools. I figured it out based on this answer over here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48793449/10681206