# Failed to load. See output window (ctrl+Alt+O) for more information

Tags: javascript, gulp

```
`"use strict";

// region Importss
var gulp = require('gulp');
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('./gulp-tasks');
gulp.task('default', ['compile']);`
```

above is my code in gulpfile.js
my gulp version is 4.0.0

it show error when I try to compile it, anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a program error message, what are you using to run that

Comment: I am using visual studio 2017

Comment: [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35889975/gulp-task-failing-when-run-from-vs-2015-task-runner-explorer-but-not-from-comma) seems it might still affect 2017

Comment: Thanks @PatrickEvans I will try to solve the problem

Comment: @PatrickEvans, I managed to compile the code using visual studio 2017, the error is about the code not the IDE.